# Join two tables in Hibernate with Criteria API and Annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations, criteria

I want to join 2 tables in MySQL with Hibernate Annotations and Criteria
Like for example:

I have 2 tables,  candidates and jobs, having 2 columns each:

- candidates: candID & candName
- jobs: jobID & jobName

  ```
                          candidates                     jobs       
                candID    candName          jobID          jobName
                    1          abc                       1               job1
                    2          xyz                       2               job2
  ```

i need to create a query in Criteria in hibernate     as:

```
 select candName  ,jobName    from candidates as c ,jobs as j  
 where c.candID = j.jobID where candName = abc and jobName=job1
```

what will be the criteria query for that and most importantly what will i write in my annotation class ( as i am using spring annotations) and do i need to write anything in my applicantioncontext.xml...

Thanks

I will be really greatful if you can help me with that as i am struggling for last  3 days for it with no success

thanks

Comment: How do your entities look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table per class Hierarchy, where Candidates and Jobs correspond to their database entities

```
public class Candidates{
//define Generative stretegy if this is primary key, and other JPA annotations, with cascade
  private Long CandId;
//getters and setters
//define other properties here

}
/*Like wise for Jobs class */
```

I donot check inside an IDE/Compiler but it should be somelike below

```
Criteria c1 = session.createCriteria(Candidates.class,candidate);
Criteria j1 = session.createCriteria(Jobs.class,jobs);
c1.setProjection(Property.forName(candName));
j1.setProjection(Property.forName(jobName));
c1.add(Restrictions.and(Property.eqName(candidate.candId,jobs.jobId)));
j1.add(Restrictions.and(jobs.jobName,"job1"));
c1.addCriterion(j1);
```

Comment: thanks ,what exactly is this candidate and jobs where i will declare them ?

Comment: thanks for your reply ,what exactly is this candidate and jobs and where i will declare them ?  as we can only write String here.. createCriteria(Candidates.class,candidate);  createCriteria(Jobs.class,jobs);      also when i use this  c1.setProjection(candidate.candName);   it says candidate.candName must be a projection ,where as thats a string

Comment: @Narayan
`setProjection` method takes `Projections` type argument, what type of varaiable is `candidate.candName` and `jobs.jobName` here?

Comment: @VisruthCV: candName and jobname are properties/fields, chk update!

Comment: I guess there's no method as addCriterion for criteria