# HQL join tables

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, hql

Does anyone know how to convert a code like this from SQL to HQL in Hibernate?

```
SELECT 
     a.Column1, 
     a.Column2, 
     b.Column1, 
     b.Column3 
  FROM 
     table1 a, 
     table2 b 
 WHERE 
     a.Column1 = b.Column3 AND
     a.Column2 = 'some user input'
```

Table1 and Table2 are properly mapped in Hibernate.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the Criteria based queries?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes i am aware of Criteria based queries, however, i am not entirely sure on how to do a subqueries correctly with it.

Comment: Try these:
[Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083660/join-two-tables-in-hibernate-with-criteria-api-and-annotation) and [Link2](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/examples/criteria/hibernate-criteria-join-api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Criteria query would look something like this where Supplier is TableA and the products is TableB.

```
session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Supplier.class); 
criteria.createCriteria("products","p");
criteria.add( Restrictions.like("name", "some user input");
 List<Supplier> list = criteria.list();
for (Supplier object : list) {
    //Do stuff with supplier if needed
}
```

products is a one to many relationship on supplier.

Comment: how can i compare the list from that criteria query to another table. like 'a.Column1 = b.Column2'?

Comment: Is there no relationship mapped?

Comment: Yes so by stating **createCriteria("products","p")**  hibernate is creating the join to the other table for you by reading the mappings.

Comment: so after i set a relationship, and created the query. iinstead of using 'supplier.class' to cast into the ScrollableResults i should use 'p'?

Comment: The p is simply there for an alias.  Lets say you wanted to add a restriction or where clause for only products where the name started with L .  Then I would do something like  criteria.add( Restrictions.like("p.name", "L%");

Comment: Ok, got it. But after i get the query i need to get the result, with 'Iterator' or 'ScrollablResults' and i need to cast a class into the query. Would'supplier.class' work in this case

Comment: List<Supplier> list = criteria.list();
  
  for (Supplier supplier: list) {
   
  }